# Source host doesn't have access to Internet, but can SSH to host that has; how can I rsync to a third, Internet host?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

This is the command I used to run from my SOURCE machine

```
rsync -Rrlt --progress --delay-updates ./my_folder root@machine-on-same-network:/home/me/.
```

Now I need to copy over this same folder to a TARGET machine that is on the Internet.

My SOURCE machine doesn't have access to the Internet, however, that SOURCE machine could connect via SSH to a machine that does have access to the internet.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't rsync the folder to the intermediary machine and from there rsync to the target machine?

Comment: yes there is actually a good reason for that, hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this. The [rsync Web site](http://rsync.samba.org/firewall.html) explicitly lists **five** different methods to do this. They state at the top of the page:

> If you have a setup where there is no way to directly connect two systems for an rsync transfer, there are several ways to get a firewall system to act as an intermediary in the transfer.

I find method two especially simple: change your ~/.ssh/config file on your source machine to include these lines:

```
 Host target
   ProxyCommand nohup ssh middle nc -w1 %h %p
   User target_user
```

Here *target* is the destination pc, where you are *target_user*, and *middle* is the pc acting as a g-between. *nc*  is obviously *netcat*, *nohup* suppresses an annoying warning, *-w1* shuts down the running instance of netcat, *%p% uses the default port.

With this in place, the command to perform the backup becomes:

```
 rsync -Rrlt /src/ target:/dest/
```

Should you wish more discussion of these methods for any reason, a good place is [this blog page](http://toddharris.net/blog/2005/10/23/rsyncing-through-an-ssh-tunnel/).

Comment: Yes the link to the rsync page was all I was looking for indeed. Cheers.